# Unit and integration testing of microservice architecture

Tags: unit-testing, testing, repository, azure

I am investigating how to test a project. Some information about the project:

- Microservice architecture, with roughly 20 services. About 10 of them
  with a separate database.
- We use ServiceFabric
- There is a fair bit of service to service communication.
- Each server is a separate repo. With no references to each other.
- There is one common Nuget package, where some things like date to
  string. This repo does not have any references to any other repos

I would like to be able to write both unit and integration tests, but I am focusing on unit tests for now. 
The problem is better illustrated by an example.

Let say I want to test AggrigateAllOrdersForUsers in the OrderMs. The code looks like this:

```
List<AggrigatedOrderTDO> AggrigateAllOrdersForUsers (List<Guid> userIds)
{
var internalUserIds= userService.GetUsers(userIds); -> calls User ms via REST API
var orders = orderHistoryServer.GetOrdersForUsers(internalUserIds); -> calls OrderHistory ms via REST API

var orderTypes = constantsServer.GetOrderTypes(); -> calls Constants ms via REST API
var validTypes = GetValidOrderTypesForOrderAggrigation(orderTypes) -> internal function

return Aggrigate(internalUserIds, orders , validTypes); -> internal function
}
```

Orders in this case is a complicated object. It has reference to multiple other classes, where ids need to match. It is not trivial to create, and I would like to reuse the code for creating the fake data.

How would you go about mocking/stubbing/faking the external calls here? It is easy to create a fake for userService, but where do I put it in my source tree? Everything is separate. Do duplicate the fakes? Do I create a new userServiceFake repo? Do I go about it in a completly different way?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The way I've handled it in the past is to have each api in the chain have two client libraries.

One is the normal, 'connect to the api server' client lib. The second reads its responses from files rather than connecting to a server.

Both these libraries live in with the Solution which contains the api itself.

- Integration tests, for that service, use the normal client. But I save the raw responses I get when I run the tests.
- In my dependent services Unit tests, I reference the file based client nuget package, along with the Integration test generated sample responses.

If I have a chain of services all dependent on each other in this way I can follow the same pattern at each stage. In this way the file based client hides any sub dependencies.

Of course you could equally well implement an in memory mock client or something and publish that. The benefit of the file based approach is that

- There is a lot of code reuse from the real client.
- When the service changes you can quickly generate the new expected responses by running the integration tests
- If you need a custom response in a particular unit test, you can edit the response file.

Comment: For this to work, Order needs a reference to User repo where User and UserFake is. Is this correct? In my case there is no such reference. There is no dependency between projects.

Comment: in your example, orders are generated by orderHistoryServer which I presume is an api call to a microservice? in your unit tests you would inject orderHistoryServer_FileBasedClient

Comment: Yes. Does this mean that you run an instance of  orderHistoryServer_FileBasedClient in your test enviroment? There is an actuall network request generated within the test?

Comment: orderHistoryServer_FileBasedClient doesnt generate network requests. its just reads the expected response  from a file.

Comment: userService.GetUsers is implemented in the Order server. It is a wrapper class which sends an async html requests to Order server. It knows where the user server is based on an enviroment variable. There is no common code between services

Comment: you would also be injecting userService_FileBasedClient and so on in your unit test

Comment: userService is a local class in the Order microservice which is a repo with no dependencies. You are saying that I should override this by an injected class from the User microservice/Repo? Do they not need a common interface for this to work? There is no link between them, appart from a http interface which is configured using enviroment variables.

Comment: your example is somewhat confusing. in it you state that "userService.GetUsers(userIds); -> calls User ms" i assume this means a REST API call, which in your unit test you want to replace with a mocked version

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Will update

Comment: OK so, it cant be that AND "userService is a local class in the Order microservice which is a repo with no dependencies"

Comment: Maybe it is the wrong description by me?

userService is in instance of UserCommunicator, which is a class in the Order repo. All services which interface with the User Microservice has a copy-ish of this class. 
The UserCommunicator is a helper class for sending/getting info from the User MS via REST. 

The GetUsers function converts the input to JSON, then sends a HttpRequestMessage to an endpoint that is configured by env variables. 
var request = CreateRelayRequest(HttpMethod.Get, $"{_endpointConfiguration.UserEndpoint}/GetAll");

Comment: ok so replace all that with the two clients as i suggest

Comment: I think i understand what you are saying, but i dont understand how. For this to work, the order repo has a reference to the user repo and the user repo implements a userCommunicator and a userCommunicatorFake, both are impls of IOrderCommunicator. Order then uses dependency injection to determine which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that doesn't really *do* anything, besides calling other methods or functions. So really, you won't be testing any real behavior, since the actual work is done in all the other methods or functions. If their corresponding tests pass, then you know that this is most likely to work.

So, having said that, you can (and really, should) test the invocation of the methods here, to know that your overall process does work. You can assert the output of the method (given the input), but also (using your preferred unit testing library) make sure that all methods are called. Of course, the implementation of the other classes are to be mocked.